# Why this function executes two times?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I have a simple tkinter window that converts from mass to weight. Code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

win = Tk()

Label(win, text='Mass to Weight').pack()
entry = IntVar(win)
entry.set(1)
e1 = Entry(win, textvariable=entry)

us = StringVar(win)
us.set('Mass')
dm1 = ttk.OptionMenu(win, us, 'Mass', 'Mass', 'Weight')

def callback(*args):
    su = e1.get()
    go = (int(float(su))*10)

    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e1.insert(0, str(go))
    dm1.configure(state='disabled')

us.trace('w', callback)

e1.pack()
dm1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Mass is multiplied by 10 to get weight. So callback function is called when 'us' value is changed to weight. But the problem is that this function is called two times. For example when I want to convert 10 Kg mass to weight, It returns 1000 instead of 100. Please not that returned valued is placed within same entry widget
Thanks.

Comment: It correctly multiplies by 10 when I run it.  By the way, you should add the python tag (and the python-version tag).  The code's syntax will get highlighted and more people will see your question.

Comment: What was your input and output?

Comment: 1 -> 10, 10 -> 100, 333 -> 3330, etc. I do have to restart the program to try the next one since it goes unresponsive though. I should also note that I'm running python 2 not 3.

Comment: I tagged it with my python version, maybe its a problem only in this version.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 on win7 and it still works as expected. Only runs once.

Comment: Why don't you just use command option?

Comment: I'm on 3.6.2 on WIndows10 and I get the expected results, seems to all check out for me. The way that you're going about this, using an OptionMenu with trace as a "pseudo-button" is a little unusual though.........